# Evaluate $\iint_D \frac{y^4}{x}\, dxdy$ where $D$ is contained between the parabolas $x = 1 - y^2$ and $x = 4(1 - y^2)$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate $\int \int_D \dfrac{y^4}{x} dxdy$ where $D$ is contained between the parabolas $x = 1 - y^2$ and $x = 4(1 - y^2)$.

After sketching the graph of both parabolas, It seems that I can integrate it with respect to the y-axis without having to break it into subregions. However, if I integrated with respect to the x-axis, then I would have to break it into subregions.

I got $D = \{-1 \le y \le 1, 4 - 4y^2 \le x \le 4\}$ for the region I am integrating over.

This gives $\int^{1}_{y = -1} \int_{x = 4-4y^2}^4 \dfrac{y^4}{x} dxdy$. However, I'm unsure if this is the correct answer. When I type it into online calculators, It seems that they cannot solve it. However, looking at the graph  of the two parabolas $x = 1 - y^2$ and $x = 4(1 - y^2)$, it seems that it should be the correct solution.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review this my work and provide feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are viewing $x$ as a function of $y$ i.e $x = g(y)$ then $x$ is thought of as the height-coordinate. To determine the range of $y$ we simply set $(1-y^2) = 4(1-y^2)$ which implies $y = \pm 1$ and so,

$$\textbf{Answer} = \int_{-1=y}^1 \int_{x = 1-y^2}^{4(1-y^2)} \frac{y^4}{x} \ \ dx \ dy$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, Faraad. I think your answer is correct. Would you be so kind as to help me understand why my answer is incorrect? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You have the wrong bounds for $x$. They give them to you in the problem. Replace $x$ with $y$ and see that if this problems was given in the form $y = 1-x^2$ and $y = 4(1-x^2)$ then you would say the bounds for $y$ are ? The confusion is that we are used to drawing graphs for function $y = f(x)$ and not $x = g(y)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance! Your posts have been enlightening.